# In dexie(Wrapper for IndexedDB) how can I use 'LIKE' like in sql to search

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I want to search some data stored in `IndexedDb` using `dexie`. I looked the doc. for anything like `LIKE` in sql for `dexie`. is there any function for this purpose ?

Comment: `startsWith(key: string): Collection;` something like the function I wanted

Answer (score 4):

There's an answer for this question in a github issue: https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/146

Comment: And this answer as well. Maybe more straight forward: https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/issues/267